# Remove Files of given range in bash/shell/unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have files of below name format.

```
test_1_452161_987654321.ARC  
test_1_452162_987654321.ARC  
test_1_452163_987654321.ARC  
.  
.  
.  
test_1_452190_987654321.ARC
```

i.e i need to delete 30 files in the above case where user will give the below inputs

```
Start_File = 452161  
End_File   =  452190
```

How to delete the above series files? (i am new to bash/shell programming i tried using while loop and remove which dint work so seeking experts help)

***My Code***

```
echo "Enter Start File"
read start
echo "Enter End File"
read end

i=$start
j=$end

while [$i -le $j]; do
rm *$i*.ARC
((i++))
done
```

Comment: Your script will work if you add a space after the `[` and before the `]` in the while test. You might want to use `rm -f` to avoid error messages if there are gaps in the file name range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace everything after fourth line by

```
for ((i=$start; i<=$end; i++)); do
  echo rm *_${i}_*.ARC
done
```

If everything looks fine, remove `echo`.

Comment: Underscore(_) will always present before and after my series(i.e _452161_ ). i added echo rm *_$i_*.ARC which is not working. How do i add that? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk + xargs`:

```
printf "%s\n" test*ARC | awk -v s=452161 -v e=452190 -F_ '$3 >= s && $3 <= e' | xargs rm
```

awk is splitting file names on `_` and then checking 3rd field is within start/end range.

Comment: Anubhava thanks for your answer. Definitely i will try this approach and revert.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in expanding a sequence [additional documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion). The code below will echo the file names you are interested in based on the provided start and end input.

```
echo -n "Enter Start File => "; read start
echo -n "Enter End File => "; read end

for file in *{$start..$end}*
do
    echo $file
done
```

*EDIT:* Variable expansion works in zsh but not bash

Comment: You can't use variables in `..` ranges.

Comment: Variables work in zsh but not in bash you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to your options, you can use [`seq`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq):

```
echo "Enter Start File"
read start
echo "Enter End File"
read end

for i in $(seq $start $end)
do
    rm -f *_${i}_*.ARC
done
```

To me this seems clean and clear.